# checking if a array has numbers in it from 0 to length -1 in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have got an assignment and i'll be glad if you can help me with one question
in this assignment, i have a question that goes like this:

**write a function that receives an array and it's length.
the purpose of the function is to check if the array has all numbers from 0 to length-1, if it does the function will return 1 or 0 otherwise.The function can go through the array only one.
you cant sort the array or use a counting array in the function**

i wrote the function that calculate the sum and the product of the array's values and indexes

```
int All_Num_Check(int *arr, int n)
{
 int i, index_sum = 0, arr_sum = 0, index_multi = 1, arr_multi = 1;

 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (i != 0)
       index_multi *= i;
    if (arr[i] != 0)
       arr_multi *= arr[i];

    index_sum += i;
    arr_sum += arr[i];
  }

 if ((index_sum == arr_sum) && (index_multi == arr_multi))
    return 1;

 return 0;
}
```

i.e: length = 5, arr={0,3,4,2,1} - that's a proper array
length = 5 , arr={0,3,3,4,2} - that's not proper array

unfortunately, this function doesnt work properly in all different cases of number variations.
i.e: length = 5 , {1,2,2,2,3}

thank you your help.

Comment: `the purpose of the function is to check if the array has all numbers from 0 to length-1,`..sorry, what? Can you rephrase?

Comment: I don't know if understood the question right.  Do you mean that the array should contain a number in the range [0, n-1] in every position, and that all numbers should be different?  Please rephrase if not.

Comment: Please use standard English capitalization.

Comment: for exmple, you have 5 items array {0,1,2,3,4}, you can see that it has all numbers from 0 to length -1 (0,1,2,3).

Comment: Also, `bool` would be more suited as a return type for that function.

Comment: What I mean is: they have to be ordered: `{0,1,2,3,4}`, or they can be unordered: `{1,3,4,2,0}`?

Comment: @mega5800 The length of the array with 5 items is 5, so it should contain all integer numbers from 0 to 4. The example "(0,1,2,3)" doesn't seem to match the question.

Comment: Is there a limit to the array length (like maybe 16 or 32)? Or you could conceivably receive an array with 999 integers?

Comment: @pmg the array doesnt have a const limit. each time i run the program i can set new limit

Comment: @Bodo you are right, i meant that (0,1,2,3,4) is an exmple of a "good" array

Comment: @CacahueteFrito i cant sort the array

Comment: What do you mean: "cannot [...] use a counting array"? Can you use a flag array (`_Bool helper[n]`)?

Comment: @pmg i cant use a bool helper

Comment: @mega5800, can you specify the range of values `arr[i]` & `n` can take?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I thought for a while, and then i realized that it is a highly contrained problem.
Things that are not allowed:

1. Use of counting array.
2. Use of sorting.
3. Use of more than one pass to the original array.

Hence, i came up with this approach of using XOR operation to determine the results.

1. a ^ a = 0
2. a^b^c = a^c^b.

Try this:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int arr[5], i, n , temp = 0;
    for(i=0;i<n; i++){
        if( i == 0){
            temp = arr[i]^i;
        }
        else{
            temp = temp^(i^arr[i]);
        }
    }
    if(temp == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

To satisfy the condition mentioned in the problem, every number has to occour excatly once.
Now, as the number lies in the range `[0,.. n-1]`, the looping variable will also have the same possible range.
Variable `temp` , is originally set to 0.
Now, if all the numbers appear in this way, then each number will appear excatly twice.
And XORing the same number twice results in 0.
So, if in the end, when the whole array is traversed and a zero is obtained, this means that the array contains all the numbers excatly once.
Otherwise, multiple copies of a number is present, hence, this won't evaluate to 0.

Comment: can you please explain exactly how it works, its seems interesting

Comment: I've added explaination in the answer.

Comment: @taurus05 thank you very much for your solution, you really did great!!!

Comment: Mention not @mega5800. It would have been much better, if you would have tried on your own to craft the solution...

Comment: [Fails, for example, for array {1, 1, 1, 1}](https://ideone.com/M2m4lo)

Comment: [Also fails for array {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7}](https://ideone.com/84Az1X)

Comment: But, the problem is not clear as well. The OP has not mentioned the range of values `arr[i]` & `n` can take.

Answer (score 2):

Checking the sum and product is not enough, as your counter-example demonstrates.

A simple solution would be to just sort the array and then check that at every position `i`, `a[i] == i`.

Edit: The original question was edited such that sorting is also prohibited. Assuming all the numbers are positive, the following solution "marks" numbers in the required range by negating the corresponding index. 
If any array cell already contains a marked number, it means we have a duplicate.

```
int All_Num_Check(int *arr, int n) {
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      j = abs(arr[i]);
      if ((j >= n) || (arr[j] < 0)) return 0;  
      arr[j] = -arr[j];
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast response, but i cant sort it and i can go through the array only once

Comment: good one ... but "The function can go through the array only one."

Comment: @pmg Thanks. Missed that. Since the range is exactly 0..n I think it's sufficient to just check nothing is marked twice.

Comment: nice try Eran but, i can go through the array only once

Comment: I think you should use `arr[abs(arr[i])] = -arr[abs(arr[i])];` because `arr[i]` might have been negated in a previous iteration. And you should abort if `arr[abs(arr[i])] < 0`, not if `arr[i] < 0`. Example: If `arr[0] == 3` you will negate `arr[3]`, so it will be negative when you later reach `i=3`.

Comment: @Bodo yup nice catch

Comment: I really think you should put the `return 0;` in a new line, if you don't want to look for problems.